# Retrieve subscription with Stripe Parse api

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments

At the moment, I don't see any functionality to retrieve a Stripe subscription from Stripe's Parse.com module. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parse API library is extremely old (only one subscription per customer), so the subscription object is just part of the customer object.

Comment: do you know about this? https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Stripe.html#.Subscriptions

Comment: also, it doesnt really matter to me that the customer only has 1 subscription. the problem is that i dont know how to get that subscription?

Comment: And the Stripe.Subscriptions that Parse provides has 0 methods, just log / print out the entire customer object and you should see the subscription

Comment: I know, it's a shame that they left it completely blank. I did exactly what you just suggested, however I'm now having trouble parsing through the massive JSON object is returned. Do you know how to do this with Parse's api? They pretty much forbid the use of jQuery.